# How to show GWT Dialog Box at the end of UI initialization if there're async calls to server?

Tags: java, gwt

I initialize UI, adding all the elements to a VerticalPanel and at the end of initialization I check whether user password is expiring or not. If it is expiring I show a DialogBox with warning.

One of the element of this page is a TabPanel with a DataGrid and all the data is taken from server asynchronously. So the problem is that when Password Expiration dialog box appears it is behind DataGrid rows. When I inspect elements in Chrome I see that there're PopupGlassPanel -> DialogBox -> Table (with content). But the picture should be: Table (with content) -> PopupGlassPanel -> DialogBox.

But I cannot do anything with async calls to the server for retrieving data. Is it possible to  control such things in order all data is retrieved from server and only after it my Dialo Box is shown?

Initialization method looks like:

```
public void initUI() {
    final VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();

    Panel outer = new VerticalPanel();
    DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder(); //this class contains DataGrid and makes async calls to server for data
    outer.add(dataHolder.getContent());
    tabPanel.add(outer, "Important Data", true);

    mainPanel.add(tabPanel);

    checkPasswordExpiration(getPwdExpiring());

    RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
}

//...........

private void checkPasswordExpiration(int days) {
//...
//Show dialog box
//...
}
```

Comment: Are you having z-index problem with dialog box or is dialog box showing at the wrong time?

Comment: Yes, there's a problem with z-index. But setting z-index to gwt-DialogBox won't help. Because DataGrid rows won't be greyed out and still be active in background at time when all the other part of UI is behind PopupGlassPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `checkPasswordExpiration()` after the async call returns. To do this you should get the async callback (`onSuccess()`) to fire an event for which you have a handler that will call `checkPasswordExpiration(getPwdExpiring());` You can use `EventBus` to fire the event in and to add a handler.

Comment: Thank you. I think this variant is optimal one. I have some troubles with straight usage of such approach. But it is a design problem I think.